# How to use IDA Pro debug Android Application?

Tags: android

Any person can give some examples or resources about how to use IDA Pro debug Android Application?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! Please edit your question to include what you want to know specifically. As it stands your question is too broad. Once you edited your question you can then simply ask for it to be reopened (both are links right below your post).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Although IDA lets you reverse `.class` files, there are tools that convert the Java byte code back to source code and are preferred for this)
It's pretty common nowadays to compile libraries and use [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) to develop a part of your app in C/C++.

Those parts will be compiled to an `.so` files, which can be invoked using the java code.
You can reverse those files, they should even contain some symbols in a form of `package_classname_method` to know who can invoke them.
Other than that, I don't think ida can offer something to reverse android apps.
The point is - Ida is not a general app reversing tool, it has a specific use.

That being said, here are examples:

- [IDA Dalvik debugger: tips and tricks](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=809)
- [Reverse-Engineering-and-Tampering](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/blob/master/Document/0x05c-Reverse-Engineering-and-Tampering.md#ida-pro)
- [Remote debugging using IDA Pro](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/guide-debugging-android-binaries/#gref)